# Standard error computation in a non-linear model

Tags: maximum-likelihood, standard-error, delta-method

I have the following model:
$$
Y_t = \varphi(X_t^\prime\beta)\times Z_t 
$$
where $X_t$ is a vector of exogenous regressors and $Y_t$ and $Z_t$ are random variables and $\phi$ is a cumulative normal distribution. Can I use quasi-MLE standard errors of individual parameters of the beta vector or it is necessary to use a delta method to obtain SE? I believe they should be similar but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use quasi-MLE standard errors, if you are sure that quasi-MLE really works. Both MLE and quasi-MLE are estimation methods which ensure that your estimates are asymptotically normal:

$$\sqrt{n}(\hat{\theta}_n-\theta_0)\to N(0, \Sigma)$$

So you immediately get the standard errors of estimates. Now Delta method is used to get the asymptotic result for the function of $\hat{\theta}_n$. To be more precise Delta method says that for function $g$:

$$\sqrt{n}(g(\hat{\theta}_n)-g(\theta_0))\to N(0,g'_{\theta_0}\Sigma (g'_{\theta_0})^T),$$

where $g'_{\theta_0}$ is the jacobian of $g$ at the point $\theta_0$.

So if you apply MLE or quasi MLE to your original model, then you are fine, i.e. you do not need to use Delta method.